# Checklist for cited references, including nasty details

Tags: citations

My personal library (.bib-files) contains references which I gathered from various sources, including academic search engines. This includes problems like:

- Some information are missing
- Journal names might be abbreviated or not
- Capitalization might differ

What is a good checklist to ensure that the references are in a acceptable state?

Comment: Your check-list is going to depend on what your definition is of an acceptable reference, surely.

Comment: @Nicholas: I think he is asking what the community considers a acceptable reference

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best strategy for dealing with a reference database (be that a citation manager or just a .bib file), is to clean everything when you initially add it. Otherwise going through these things later, when you need put together a reference list, is a major pain and prone to error. Establishing a standard set of formatting rules/procedures up front is always your best bet.

Comment: My group once hired a master student to do this ;)

Comment: @gerrit I have been that student in the past.